# MATLAB - why is it complaining about @-folders for classdef'd objects?

Tags: oop, matlab

I've been writing OOP MATLAB code for quite some time. However, I'm now running MATLAB code on a Windows machine for the first time.

I have the following code:

```
classdef myClass < handle
    properties
        i
    end

    methods
        function obj = myClass()
            obj.i = 0;
        end

        function say(obj)
            obj.i = obj.i + 1;
            fprintf('This is time #%i you invoked me!\n', obj.i);
        end
    end
end
```

Seems pretty innocuous. I try to instantiate an object and I get this:

```
>> m = myClass;
Error using myClass
Error: File: myClass.m Line: 1 Column: 10
A class definition must be an "@" directory.
```

I've never used an @-folder in all my time writing OOP MATLAB code. My understand is it's required if class methods are written separately from the classdef file (mine's not) or if it's using the old-style MATLAB class syntax (mine's not).

I think I know what the deal is and I wanted to see if there's a workaround: My working directory is of the form

```
C:\Users\DangKhoa@MyCompany.com\Documents\MATLAB
```

Is that `@` throwing MATLAB off and making the computer think I'm in an @-folder? If it is, is there a workaround (aside making a new user on my computer, obviously - and that probably isn't doable)? If not, what is going on?

Comment: It seems very likely that the `@` is messing things up. You can have your user-generated code installed anywhere, though. You simply change the "user path" using the `userpath` function, and Matlab will look for your code there.

Comment: @-folders are from an older version of Matlab. In 2008 the syntax was dramatically re-written.

Comment: @slayton: [What do you mean](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/organizing-classes-in-folders.html)?

Comment: Are you able to try running it on Linux, in a folder like `~/Documents/test@test/myClass.m`? If this works, it's a Windows thing. Also, I have doubts about the '@' being the problem, as the '@' must also be the *first* character in the folder name...but I could be wrong.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - I doubt that's the problem too, but I don't know what else could be happening. I no longer have access to MATLAB on my home Linux box, could someone else test this for me?

Comment: @DangKhoa: I'm at work now, tested it, and indeed: the '@' is the problem! Seems like a valid reason to file a bug report with the Mathworks to me.

Comment: @DangKhoa: I just tried making a symlink to the `test@test` dir, but Matlab isn't fooled by that. I take it that's the same on Windows, so: not an option.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis did you run the test on a Linux box? I'm filing the bug report now. "Glad" to see this is a platform-agnostic problem.

Comment: @DangKhoa: Yup, Ubuntu 12.04, Matlab R2010b 32 bit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like yes, the `@` in the middle of the folder is causing the error. I filed a bug report with The MathWorks.

Comment: They responded and added this to an existing bug report.